# Exclude elements from click event handler (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have defined an event handler for some elements on the page.

```
var selector = "div, select, input, button";
$(selector).on('click', function (e) {
    //deactivate function of the elements and prevent propagation
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    //...
    //dialog is loaded and created here
    //e.g. $(body).append('<see-dialog-html-from-below>');
    //...
    alert('selector click');
}
```

I then add (and remove) a dialog to the DOM at runtime (one dialog at a time).
A simplified dialog could look like this:

```
<div id="dialog" class="ui vertical menu">
    <div class="item">
        <label for="constraints">Constraints:</label>
        <select id="constraints" name="constraints">
            <option value="0">option 0</option>
            <option value="1">option 1</option>
            <option value="2">option 2</option>
            <option value="3">option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="item clearfix">
            <div class="ui buttons">
              <div id="save_button" class="ui green button">Save</div>
              <div class="or"></div>
              <div id="cancel_button" class="closebutton ui button">Cancel</div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I bind more click actions to the cancel and save buttons when I create the dialog.

The problem is the select box. It triggers the first click event that I defined above.

How can I exclude all elements in the dialog box from being included in the first event handler?

Comment: If you want to exclude the `select` just remove it from the `selector` variable.

Comment: You could make sure the element is not a descendant of `#dialog` or possibly depending on your markup use `>` to limit the selector to direct children of some element (hard to say without seeing the all markup) Or something like `*:not(#dialog) select` and so on as selectors.

Comment: Look at the target -> `if (e.target.hasClass())` or something alike

Comment: @EricMartinez: I cannot exclude the selector. And there could also be other elements in the dialog that will get targeted with the click event handler (like buttons and div containers).

Comment: @Mikey: Looking at the classes would require checking each child element of the dialog.
I could add a class to each element of the dialog in its template and exclude it when I create the click event. But that would introduce another dependency into the application (which would be defficult to maintain and easy to forget).

Comment: Look at this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp, exclude items in a different class

Comment: @reggie Ok I see. Yes that is really a bad idea now that I read your question for the second time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If clicking the `select` triggers the alert, in the first event handler, then the dialog already exists in the page by the time you execute `$(selector).on('click', ...)`. In that case you can exclude some elements from the selector with `not`.

```
$(selector).not('#dialog').on('click', ...)
```

This will bind a `click` handler to all elements matched by the selector but excluding elements matched in the `not`. If you have several dialogs consider using a CSS class like `ui-dialog` and using `not('.ui-dialog')`.

**EDIT**: But note that if your dialog is placed inside a `div` and you do not stop the propagation of the custom events then any click in the popup will bubble up and also trigger the handler in the parent `div`. Just ensure you use `e.stopPropagation();` when adding handlers to the dialog actions.

Comment: No, it does not exist. I load the dialog's template asynchronously (and store it), but the element is created and destroyed at runtime. As far as I understand, jQuery's 'on' replaced the 'live' method that was previously used. Which means it will trigger on dynamically added content. I did try your suggestion and the alert was triggered regardless.

Comment: Hmmm, and I cannot do something like this: $(selector + ' :not(#dialog)'). The selector has multiple parts, so the :not() would only apply to the last part...

Comment: I was not able to replicate your behavior until I figured you place the popup inside a div. So it's a matter of event propagation and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this for now by adding a click event handler for all elements of the dialog like so:

```
$('#dialog > ' + selector).on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); //prevent the event from bubbling through the DOM hierarchy
});
```

If you know a solution how I could exclude the dialog at the time of creation of the handler, please let me know.

Comment: You're over complicating things. Instead of using 'select' as the selector, use a class that *select* inputs inside dialogs wouldn't have. Or on the contrary, make sure that *select* inputs inside dialogs use a class that you would exclude with jquery's *not* selector.